# The normal order of $\nu(n)$ and its normal distribution

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, analytic-number-theory

I understand that for $\nu(n)$, the number of divisors of $n$, let me denote $\log_2 x=\log\log x$. Then $$\sum_{n\le x}\Big(\nu(n)-\log_2x\Big)^2=O(x\log_2x)$$

The book told me about the theorem (due to Erdos and Kac), for $S(x;\alpha,\beta)=\#\left\{ n\le x : \alpha\le\dfrac{\nu(n)-\log_2n}{\sqrt{\log_2(n)}}\le\beta\right\}:=\#S$, then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{S(x;\alpha,\beta)}{x}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\alpha}^\beta e^{-t^2/2} dt$$

I want to prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\le x}\Big(\nu(n)-\log_2n\Big)^2\ll x\log_2 x$ by using the theorem stated above.

What I am confused is that if $n\in S$ then $\displaystyle \delta(n):=\left|\dfrac{\nu(n)-\log_2 n}{\sqrt{\log_2 (n)}}\right|\le \max(|\alpha|,|\beta|)$ and if we choose $|\alpha|,|\beta|\le \sqrt x$ then the statement I want follows for $n\in S$, but what about $n\not\in S, n\le x$? I confuse about the phrase "normally distributed". What does it mean exactly in this sense?

As I guess, if we choose $\alpha,\beta$ that $\beta-\alpha$ is wide enough then $\delta(n)$ that satisfies the condition in $S$ would be wide enough, too. Therefore, the number of terms left from the distribution (the term on the left and right part of normal distribution) would be small.

How can I add the left terms that I mentioned to cover all $n\le x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I proved it by using the method that resembled Turan that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{1<n\le x}\nu(n) & =x\log_2x+O(x) \\
\sum_{n\le x} \nu(n)^2&= x(\log_2x)^2+O(x\log_2x)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and by partial summation
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{1<n\le x}(\log_2 n)^2 & =\sum_{1<n\le x}1\cdot(\log_2n)^2 = (\left[\,x\right]-1)\log^2_2x-\int_2^x (\left[\,t\right]-1)\cdot 2\log_2 t\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{t\log t}\right) dt\\
&= x(\log_2 x)^2+O(\log^2_2 x)+O(x\log_2 x)= x(\log_2 x)^2+O(x\log_2 x)\\
\sum_{1<n\le x} \nu(n)\log_2 n & = \sum_{n\le x} \nu(n)\cdot \log_2 n=\Big(x\log_2 x+O(x)\Big)(\log_2 x)-\int_2^x (t\log_2 t+O(t))\left(\dfrac{1}{t\log t}\right) dt \\
& = x(\log_2 x)^2+O(x\log_2 x)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Hence, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{1<n\le x}(\nu(n)-\log_2 n)^2 & = \sum \nu(n)^2-2\sum\nu(n)\log_2n+\sum(\log_2 n)^2 = O(x\log_2 x)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
as desired. Therefore, almost all numbers $n$ have $\log_2 n$ numbers of prime factors as Hardy and Ramanujan stated (I find their theorem indeed elegant).

Comment: what do you mean you proved using the method of Turan? The solution you write *is* the method of Turan.

Comment: Because I use the Turan method for his proof on $\displaystyle\sum (\nu(n)-\log_2 x)^2$ for the first $2$ equations. Then I used the partial summation for the rest. What's the point of your question?

Comment: The point of the question is to make sure that you know what is the Turan method. You seem to be confusing it quite a lot with something else.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in general to show that weak convergence implies convergence of moments. One needs some extra assumption, which in your example just happens to be the bound that you want to prove.

Comment: I didn't want to use the weaker result to prove the stronger one. However, I don't understand how to use the theorem I stated to prove it in all cases. Could you explain to me what exactly to use "normally distributed" to cover all cases? I am not able to use the probability in the cover range.

Comment: It is not possible to use the Erd\H{o}s--Kac theorem to prove what you want. The problem is that the set $S$ could have elements $m$ for which $(\nu(m)-\log_2 m )/\sqrt{\log_2 m}$ is very large in a way that it affects the second moment.